# Sum all values in a column and group by 2 minutes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to sum all values in a column "value" and group by a interval of 2 minutes

I have values like this:

```
value     TIME
0.3    2019-05-22 01:11:45---> first value 0,3
0.3    2019-05-22 01:12:16-----|
0.3    2019-05-22 01:13:26-----|second value 0,6
0.2    2019-05-22 01:13:56---|
0.4    2019-05-22 01:14:06---|
0.6    2019-05-22 01:15:43 --|third value 1,2
```

But what I really want is like this:

```
value     TIME
0.3    2019-05-22 01:11:45
0.6    2019-05-22 01:13:45
1.2    2019-05-22 01:15:45
```

---

My code in postgresql:

```
SELECT medi_sensor.value, time
FROM medi_sensor
    JOIN sensor ON medi_sensor.sensor_name = sensor.name
    JOIN mote ON num_mot=mot_id 
    JOIN room ON room_id=id_div
WHERE medi_sensor.sensor_name LIKE 'current%' AND room.name='DIV' AND time>'2019-05-22' AND time<'2019-05-24'
ORDER BY time ASC
```

The problem is how to group by minute to minute in my time column

Comment: So the minimum value becomes the starting date?

Comment: @Salman A Yes, correct.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you can use `generate_series()` to generate the values:

```
select gs.t, sum(value)
from (select ms.value, time, min(time) over () as min_time, max(time) over () as max_time
      from medi_sensor ms join
            sensor s
            on ms.sensor_name = s.name join
            mote 
            on num_mot = mot_id join
            room r
            on room_id = id_div
      where ms.sensor_name LIKE 'current%' and
            r.name = 'DIV' and
            time > '2019-05-22' and
            time < '2019-05-24'
     ) x right join lateral
     generate_series(min_time, max_time, interval '2 minute') gs(t)
     on time >= gs.t and time < ts.t + interval '2 minute'
order by gs.t;
```

I would recommend that you use table aliases for *all* column references in your query.

EDIT:

```
with x as (
      select ms.value, time
      from medi_sensor ms join
           sensor s
           on ms.sensor_name = s.name join
           mote 
           on num_mot = mot_id join
           room r
           on room_id = id_div
      where ms.sensor_name LIKE 'current%' and
            r.name = 'DIV' and
            time > '2019-05-22' and
            time < '2019-05-24'
     ) x 
select gs.ts, sum(x.value)
from (select generate_series(min_time, max_time, interval '2 minute') as ts
      from (select min(time) as min_time, max(time) as max_time
            from x
           )
      ) gs left join
      x
      on x.time >= gs.t and x.time < ts.t + interval '2 minute'
group by gs.ts
order by gs.ts;
```

Comment: Postegresql send me a error, says I cannot use right join on  a LATERAL reference.

Comment: `ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "x"
LINE 17:      generate_series(min_time, max_time, interval '2 minute'...
                              ^
DETAIL:  The combining JOIN type must be INNER or LEFT for a LATERAL reference.`

Comment: @FábioMorais . . . That is really funny.  I almost never use `RIGHT JOIN` and this was one occasion when I thought it might be useful.  In any case, I don't think the first version is logically correct.  The edited version is better.